# Post types translation

Tags: translation, localization, post-type

I try to translate post types names (Post, Page and Attachment).

I have the following code:

```
function create_skip_post_types_box () {
        $post_types = get_post_types(array('public'=>true), 'names' );
        $opt = $this->_get_option();
        $skip_types = is_array(@$opt['skip_post_types']) ? @$opt['skip_post_types'] : array();

        foreach ($post_types as $tid=>$type) {
            $checked = in_array($type, $skip_types) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
            echo
                "<input type='hidden' name='wdpv[skip_post_types][{$type}]' value='0' />" . // Override for checkbox
                "<input {$checked} type='checkbox' name='wdpv[skip_post_types][{$type}]' id='skip_post_types-{$tid}' value='{$type}' /> " .
                "<label for='skip_post_types-{$tid}'>" . ucfirst($type) . "</label>" .
            "<br />";
        }
    }
```

I tried to use ucfirst(__($type,'textdomain')) but it didn't work.

I know that for user roles we can use translate_user_role function, but what about post types?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what exactly are you trying to. Do you mind adding to your code the translation calls as you think they should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_post_types( ['public' => TRUE ], 'objects' );`. This will return the already translated post type labels and other information.

Example for tests:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    $post_types = get_post_types(
        [ 'public' => TRUE, '_builtin' => TRUE ],
        'objects' // complete information, not just the name
    );

    foreach ( $post_types as $slug => $arguments )
        print "$slug: {$arguments->labels->singular_name}<br>";

    print '<pre>' . print_r( $post_types, 1 ) . '</pre>';
});
```